# Oracle 11g - Decreasing Big Table Size

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, table, shrink, size

I want to reduce the size of a table.

> I thought if I could do this with export / import, but when I check it
> with the ESTIMATE_ONLY option, it doesn't seem to work.
>
> I have no chance of using partitioning.
>
> If I do it with CTAS (create table as select), the archive production
> will peak and the disaster database will be affected.
>
> How can I reduce the size of this table? If I do shrink, will UNDO be
> enough and how much space will be enough to add UNDO tablespace to
> overcome this problem? Do you have an estimate of how long it will
> take if I shrink?
>
> I have to be very careful as it will be done directly in the
> production database.

> Version: Oracle 11g Release 2 - Standard Edition
>
> ASM option: yes
>
> Cluster: yes
>
> Partitioning option: no
>
> Compress data pump option: no

Table size information:

```
SQL> select segment_name,sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 GB from dba_segments where owner='OWNER_NAME' and segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name=upper('TABLE_NAME') group by segment_name;

SEGMENT_NAME                                                                              GB
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
TABLE_NAME                                                                        392.493164
```

Export information (It does not work in reducing the table size.
):

```
nohup expdp "'/ as sysdba'" directory=DP_DIR tables=OWNER_NAME.TABLE_NAME ESTIMATE_ONLY=Y &
```

Output:

```
Starting "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  "/******** AS SYSDBA" directory=DP_DIR tables=OWNER_NAME.TABLE_NAME ESTIMATE_ONLY=Y
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
.  estimated "OWNER_NAME"."TABLE_NAME"            392.4 GB
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 392.4 GB
```

Best regards,

Comment: Why do you think the size of the table can be reduced?

Answer (score 0):

The most direct method shrinking a table is:

```
ALTER TABLE [table name] ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
ALTER TABLE [table name] SHRINK SPACE CASCADE;
```

More details here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/alter-table-shrink-space-online

There are some limitations to this command:

- Moving rows can cause problem with rowid based triggers.
- Rowid materialized views must be rebuilt after a shrink operation.
- The shrinking process is only available for objects in tablespaces with
  automatic segment-space management enabled.
- You can't combine the SHRINK SPACE clause with any other ALTER TABLE clauses.
- You can't shrink a cluster or a clustered table.
- You can't shrink any object with a LONG column.
- You can't shrink tables with dependent function-based indexes, domain indexes, or bitmap join indexes.
- You can't shrink tables that are the master table of an ON COMMIT
  materialized view Mapping tables of index-organized tables are not
  affected by a shrink.
- Shrinks can't be used for compressed tables, except those using Advanced Row Compression (ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED).
- The shrink operation against a table doesn't cascade to
  the LOB segments. They need to handled separately.
- You can't shrink securefile LOB segments.
- Changing the arrangement of rows in a table can have a negative impact on performance in some circumstances. Test thoroughly before making any decisions.
- After any structural change, like a move, remember to check for unusuable indexes. If you have any, rebuild them.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for response. UNDO tablespace is missing as space for shrink operation. It is very difficult to clearly predict how much free space is required for UNDO tablespace during the shrink process, there may be too much datafile loss for ASM. Does it work to use only the lob_column shrink option for the table?

Comment: "shrink table" isn't a transaction in the sense that it doesn't use UNDO and doesn't require a commit. You *can* only shrink the LOB space (it *must* be handled separately from the rest of the table), assuming it meets the criteria for LOBs (i.e. they're not SecureFile LOBs). The link I provided has details and examples. Did you read the article?

Comment: Yes I have read. Actually, I mean, does shrinking lob_segment column alone save space well? Additionally, my question about UNDO tablespace was for this; Getting ORA-30036 error during shrink.

Comment: LOB columns have their own separately defined storage; shrinking a table will not shrink the LOB columns; they must be done separately. Ergo, shrinking a LOB column by itself is the only way to shrink a LOB column and this will also save space. As for your error, you should have lead with that error code. Is this a very active table? Are there ongoing transactions during the shrink?

Comment: Shrink operation continues for 1.5 days. In this table, there is a total of 10 years of data and it is used only for select during the day, and at night the jobs do insert and update. This is one of the main tables in the database and I can say that it takes heavy processing. You are saying that the error received for UNDO tablespace is not related to shrink, but we were not getting this error before and it happened during shrink. Are you sure that it is completely independent of the shrink process?

Comment: It is indirectly related. The table can't commit new transactions while the shrink is in progress. Those new transactions are pulling up in your UNDO space.

Comment: Have there been a large number of deletes in this table, or only ever inserts and updates? What leads you to believe that much space can be reclaimed with this shrink?

Comment: Jobs only update and insert, this process takes about 5 hours. Apart from that, it is a table used only for select for 19 hours. For your other question, yes; The latest data of the last 5 years was deleted. Can adding 64GB datafile to UNDO tablespace save me? Or is there a mathematical way to calculate this? Best regards.

Comment: Since this is a one-time thing, estimating the required size will be difficult. I would start by adding a single file, set to auto-extend. Most operating systems have a file size limit of 32GB. If your file is filling up, add another before it reaches capacity. I would also recommend scheduling downtime - limiting user access to the table and not performing any inserts or updates while the shrink is going on.

Comment: I will use this command for adding datafile; "alter tablespace TABLESPACE_NAME add datafile '+ASM_GROUP_NAME' size 1G autoextend on next 1G maxsize 32767M;" I always thought it was accepting commits because the shrink operation was online. Thank you Pete for all the informations. I will inform you again.